# write system call, what's the number of bytes limit?

Tags: c, linux, types

The write system call prototype is:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

The count parameter is unsigned, and the return value is signed.

The help page says:

On success, the number of bytes written is returned (zero indicates nothing was written).
On error, -1 is returned, and `errno` is  set  appropriately.

However, it doesn't say what is the limit to the count parameter.
It still doesn't say the behavior when count is greater than `SSIZE_MAX`.

Considering write is a system call that can be used to generic devices/files/whatever, if the device supports write operations bigger than SSIZE_MAX, the returning type can't handle the real number of bytes writen.

Doesn't make sense to me to be able to pass an unsigned number of bytes and get back an signed number of bytes as a result. Why not just pass an signed number?

It feels like the prototype of the write function in sort of error prone, or at least it leaves a possible hole in the path.

Does anyone knows the details about it or where can I find this information?

Comment: I do not know it myself, but I believe the limit is of size unsigned integer. Which means, you should be able to write 4294967296 bytes at once. The return value in this case would be -1 (and you'd have to check errno to make sure that it's actually an error)

Comment: [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/write.html) "If the value of nbyte is greater than {SSIZE_MAX}, the result is implementation-defined", so the Linux manpage is lacking -- it should describe this.

Comment: It's customary to write() with smallish chunks. I'm having difficulty imagining a situation where writing gigabytes with a single syscall would be a good idea.

Comment: I don't want to write a big chunck of data.
The problem is I'm writing a platform abstraction layer and I need to create a wrapper to this function. I'm using that for sockets.
I'd like to understand the problems related to this situation.

Comment: @Marcus: For sockets, your limit is probably much much lower than `SSIZE_MAX`, and tied to the buffer sizes configured on the socket with `ioctl` and/or `setsockopt`.

Comment: Well spotted.  But I'm sort of thinking about a generic case using the write function. As I said in a comment in the post bellow:
If the device supports write operations bigger than SSIZE_MAX, the returning type can't handle the real number of bytes writen. It feels like the prototype of the write function in sort of error prone, or at least it leaves a possible hole in the path.

Comment: @Marcus: the safe bet is to check, in your wrapper code, whether `count` does not exceed `SSIZE_MAX`; or to make it an `ssize_t` and check whether it's non-negative, whichever is more to your taste. Such big blocks are a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a hard limit, it depends on what `fd` points to. If it's a file on the filesystem for instance, then the file system driver will choke if you exceed the "max file size limit", returning EFBIG error:

**EFBIG** An attempt was made to write a file that exceeds the implementation-
              defined maximum file size or the process file  size  limit.

Comment: Right, that parameter just gets passed through to the device-specific implementation.

Comment: If `fd` refers to a socket (typically a non-blocking one) one might get `ENOMEM` .

Comment: I'm not exactly worried about the sockets case.
The main point is: If the device supports write operations bigger than SSIZE_MAX, the returning type can't handle the real number of bytes writen.
It feels like the prototype of the write function in sort of error prone, or at least it leaves a possible hole in the path.

Comment: @Marcus - On what system can you realistically allocate a buffer larger than `SSIZE_MAX`? I believe available *memory* is limiting, not the device.

Comment: @Bo Persson - It is not a matter of being able to do so. The point is the function interface is strange. It says it would return the number of bytes writen, but it can't really do that. There is a big "BUT" in that described as "implementation dependent". However I could not find any information regarding that for the linux implementation.

Comment: @Marcus - But it *can* return the number of bytes unless you write more than `SSIZE_MAX`, which is about 2^63 on my system. How do you allocate a buffer larger than that?

Comment: @BoPersson it is not the point. I know I'm not going to use that. My point is the signature seems a little odd. Specially because the standard says counte > SSIZE_MAX is implementation defined. I didn't see any information in the linux man pages regarding this. I'm not trying to be picky about this. It is just a matter of understanding things.

Answer (score 1):

Googled it:

*If the value of nbyte is greater than* {SSIZE_MAX}*, the result is implementation-defined.*

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html

Comment: I know that is implementation defined (as stated in most of the posts above).
However I couldn't find a single place where that behavior is explained for a particular implementation. I believe the "implementation" means a device/filesystem/whatever implementation. Do you know some place where this situation is observed?

Comment: Implementation means whoever wrote that function. Likely your compiler provider or OS provider. Check with the docs of the compiler  or OS. Since you tagged linux, it's probably GCC with the GNU C library. Unfortunately the docs for it http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Primitives.html#I_002fO-Primitives do not specify the implementation defined behavior (may want to file a bug report on the documentation). Unless you (as many) believe "the code is the documentation", in which case just go look at the code (which is the whole point of open source).

Comment: Probably I'll place a bug report. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think remember that the system allocate the number of bytes you give to the function. But i'm not sure. Maybe you shall try size_t and ssize_t man pages.

Comment: I made a mistake, there is in the include folder, but i don't know in wich one it is =S I hope you will find it !

Comment: Don't worry! Thanks for your help. :D